# Active Admin Index Page sorting without a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, activeadmin

The relevant data consists of `Venue`, `Match` and `Broadcast` which is a join table and more for the first two.

In my `Venue` index page I am showing the number of `Broadcast`s that that venue is showing. I would like to make this sortable. Additional feature is that this should only involve `Match`s in the future, and for this I have an `active` scope on my `Broadcast` model, which returns broadcasts of matches in the future.

I would like to make this column sortable. Its definition is `venue.broadcasts.active.count`. Since it is not a column in the DB, it doesnt seem to be sortable, and since it involves a scope that changes with time, counter column will not work by default and seems way to complicated to implement my own. Is there any good way to get this to sort? I do not care too much for performance.

Comment: Have you considered making the count a column? Rails has support via a special counter_cache column. See the [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) section of the Rails Guides.

Comment: @CMaresh counter cache doesnt work for me for 1.5 reasons. For one, mine is a scoped count, not sure if the `counter_cache` handles that. and the .5 is that this is a gradual rewrite from php so until that is fully done, the counter cache wont be consistent

Comment: I was actually hoping there was a way to do a plain text sort of it, is not scalable but I have <100 rows atm so should work fine here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need sort an index page by a column that is not exist in a table, consider a client-side approach like DataTables, a jQuery table plugin.

I once used it for fast in-page search without hitting the database. Although it might look a little hacky, it served well for a considerably small number of records.

I believe you can use [the DataTables gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-datatables-rails) as [the way I googled](https://gist.github.com/EtienneDepaulis/4070962), but I did it manually:

```ruby
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
config.register_javascript 'jquery.dataTables.js'
```

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
$('#index_table_on_order_orders').dataTable(); // Specify options as you need.
```

Comment: Yup, this was what i was thinking of doing as well.. glad to know this has been tried!